# list of pointers inserting c++ eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, list, pointers, insert

I have a project referring to the movies industry.
In my main class, movieInudtsry, I have a ***list of movies*** called "movies", and in my class Worker I have for every worker ***a list of pointers of movies*** called "moviesOfWorker" , and I want this list to point to the relevant movie in "movies" list.
This is the relevant code for MovieIndustry:

```
class MovieIndustry {

list<Movie> movies;   //list of all movies
public:
void addWorkerToMovie(int idOfWorker, int codeOfMovie);
```

and this is the relevant code from addMovieToWorker in Worker class:

```
class Worker {

std::list<Movie*> moviesOfWorker;
public:
void Worker::addMovieToWorker(const Movie& toAdd){

moviesOfWorker.push_back(new Movie());
moviesOfWorker->toAdd;

}
```

this code gives me error, and I'm not sure it's right.
Question is how do I dynamic allocate the pointer to point to toAdd (which is inside list of MovieIndustry) every time? I don't want to create another instance, I want it to point to an instance from the list "movies" of my movieIndustry class, and I don't understand how to insert it everytime.
HELP..?

Comment: why not use `moviesOfWorker.push_back(toAdd);`

Comment: You need to post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Check [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't *have to* dynamically allocate the pointer. You can use the address-of operator (`&object`) to take the address of an existing object.

```
moviesOfWorker.push_back(&toAdd);
```